# Windows Forms DatePicker not behaving in XP

Tags: winforms, windows-7, windows-xp, datepicker

This issue involves a Windows Forms VB.NET application.  .NET version is 3.5

I have a datepicker control that is enabled/disabled by a checkbox.  When the user checks the box, the datepicker is enabled and they select a date.  However, for users running Windows XP, when they select a date the calendar reverts back to disabled and showing the current date (the unchecked state).

For Windows 7 users, the date is preserved and the datepicker remains in the enabled state.  I am at a loss to find a workaround for this.

Short of migrating the users to Windows 7, is there anything I can do in my code?

Here is the code for the checkbox:

```
Sub CheckboxDates() Handles ckbPaid.CheckedChanged
    If ckbPaid.Checked = True Then
        dtPaidDate.Enabled = True
    Else
        dtPaidDate.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post the smallest possible code snippet that reproduces the problem? (Just edit your question)

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, it sounds like you're getting click-through from the **DatePicker** causing it to uncheck the **CheckBox**.

Have you tried repositioning the **CheckBox** so that it's not under the calendar when it's displayed? Does that make a difference?

If it is click-through, you could try relocating the **CheckBox** or disabling it while the **DatePicker** is being used (using the **DropDown** and **CloseUp** events.)